# How to scale a Hanning Window so that the sum of its squared weights equals the length of the time series?

Tags: time-series

I am trying to implement the following method described  in "[Spectrum: Spectral Analysis Of Unevenly Spaced Paleoclimatic Time Series](https://web.archive.org/web/20170808173259/http://www.geo.uni-bremen.de/geomod/staff/mschulz/reprint/spectrum.pdf)" by Schulz and Stattegger (1997).

At the 4th page, in the paragraph above the 4th equation, I have to apply a Hanning window to a segment of my time series such that the sum of its squared weights is equal to the length of the segment I am applying my Hanning window to.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's best to make questions self-contained. It's fine to give a reference, but not to expect people to have to read it  to understand your question. Also, if links rot, the question becomes more difficult to understand.

Comment: Its best to not only give a link, but also the title and authors, at least, in xase the link dies. I have added that.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have some unscaled window weights, $v_1, ... v_n$

You'd like to scale them to scaled weights, $w_i=c\cdot v_i$, so that $\sum_i w_i^2=n$, which boils down to identifying a $c$ that does that.

So you need $\sum_i c\cdot v_i^2 =c\cdot \sum_i  v_i^2 = n$

Hence $c = \frac{n}{\sum_i v_i^2}$.